# Skip downloads in uTorrent if no seeders/0mb downloaded after 2 minutes

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I have a massive download queue whereby a lot of the files have 0 seeds and 0 peers as does my current download. Is there a preference to stop download with 0 seeds or a set limit where if 1Mb worth of data has not download within 2/3  Minutes stop download?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of but another idea is to sort the list of downloads by "download speed" or number of peers. The ones that have none, select them all by clicking on the first and holding down shift and clicking on the last and delete them all.